# How can I get ActionBar from Main(ActionBarActivity) intent Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I use ActionBarActivity intent a new Activity
but I cant call ActionBar method in Activity

```
//        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
//        getActionBar().setTitle("123");
        ActionBar actionBar =getActionBar();
//
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

will get null

```
01-14 16:29:58.712    3405-3405/com.fragment.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fragment.test, PID: 3405
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fragment.test/com.fragment.test.Ac1}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.fragment.test.Ac1.onCreate(Ac1.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
01-14 16:30:01.233    3405-3405/com.fragment.test I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3405 SIG: 9
01-14 17:12:11.968    3795-3795/com.fragment.test I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 3795 SIG: 9
```

Can I get ActionBar without change the Activity to ActionBarActivity
thanks

Answer (score 7):

if you use SUPPORT LIBRARY ► android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

you have to get the support ActionBar.

so,

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

so, you can set title, subtitle and others functions [(see all just clicking ►HERE◄)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html)

Like:

```
actionBar.setTitle("My App Title");
```

Comment: thanks reply, I use android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
but I cant getSupportActionBar();
I  cant understand..~
http://i.imgur.com/X6O6yhH.png

Comment: and If I use import android.app.ActionBar; 
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("My App Title");
will get null
'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: I fail because the class extend Activity, I change to extend ActionBarActivity and it's work.

Answer (score 1):

Or **directly you can use**,

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your new title here!");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and other methods...

Answer (score 0):

Use the support method:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Activity to extends ActionBarActivity and it's work

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated , AppCompactActivity is currently being used

Answer (score 0):

1. have your class extend AppCompatActivity
2. put "requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);" before "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" in your onCreate method
3. use "getSupportActionBar()" instead of "getActionBar()"